# Which pins belong in a "I/O region" on a MAX II CPLD?

Tags: programmable-logic

I want to use an Altera/Intel MAX II device (EPM570) to drive 20 LEDs. They all have 20mA forward voltage, for a worst-case current draw of 400mA.

The application note [AN 286](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/an/an286.pdf) explains how an Altera/Intel CPLD can be used to drive LEDs.

Regarding the maximum sink current, the application note says this in page 3:

> the EPM240 device has six GNDIO pads, which provide six I/O regions that can sink up to 130 mΑ. If you need to sink 15 mA for the outputs, you can have eight outputs per region. With the six regions of I/O between GNDIO pads, there are 48 possible outputs, each sinking 15 mA.

130mA is lower than 400mA, so I should distribute the LED pins across at least four I/O regions to avoid trouble.

But what is a *I/O region*? I can't find docs for it. The MAX II devices do have *I/O banks* but it's a different feature, enabling connection to logic devices at different voltages. And the numbers don't match: the EPM240/570 has two I/O banks according to the datasheet, and six I/O regions according to the application note.

What is the relationship between I/O pins and I/O regions (or VCCIO/GNDIO pins)? I see in the pinout that GNDIO pins are placed among I/O pins, and each I/O bank has three GNDIO pins. But how to know which pin belongs to which region?

Answer (score 0):

The best interpretation I could think of is based on the words *I/O between GNDIO pads*: all the pins whose numbers are in between two consecutive GNDIO pins belong to the same I/O region. Look at the [pinout files](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/support/literature/lit-dp.html) to find out the pin numbers for a device. E.g. for an EPM570 in TQFP100 package, the regions are:

1. pin 1 to 8 and 95 to 100
2. pin 12 to 30
3. pin 33 to 44
4. pin 47 to 58
5. pin 61 to 78
6. pin 81 to 92

Beware that regions 1 and 4 has pins controlled by different I/O banks. It's unclear which VCCIO/GNDIO pair belongs to each I/O region, so this interpretation may not be entirely correct.